# derivative of a composite function

Tags: composite, derivative

In some notes in my book they are deriving a composite function but I'm having trouble replicating it.

[image: snap]

In particular, I am trying

> g(y) = f(x^y) = f(h(y)) = f'(h(y))*h'(y) = f'(x^y)*(x_1-x_0)

but the f would be with respect to h not x so I'm not sure what I'm not seeing.

Comment: This question belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for: `d/dy f(x^y)`.
Let's see how to evaluate that:

```
d/dy f(x^y)= f'(x^y) d/dy(x^y) = f'(x^y) x^y ln(x)
```

How to calculate  `d/dy(x^y)`?
Notice that this is the elementary derivative:
`'(a^x)`, which is `a^x ln(a)`.